# Mount_upload on dynamic field with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, activemodel

I have a model named CustomFields that belongs to a main class (that has_many :custom_fields). This model has the attributes `contents` and `datatype`. I want the contents to be either a string or a uploader using carrierwave, according to the datatype of the object. I've done the following:

```
class CustomField < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize :set_uploader 

  def set_uploader
    if self.datatype == 'file'
      CustomField.mount_uploader :contents, ImageUploader
    end
  end 

end
```

It's not working because it's turning all the object's contents into uploaders, not only the 'file' datatype. How can I solve that?

Comment: You could just use two different fields to store the information, and dynamically decide which one to display with a common reader method.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess:

```
class CustomField < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader, if: :file?

  def file?
    self.datatype == 'file'
  end
end
```